# where to store HTML template files in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I'm learning Typo3 with the official documentation. Now I have achieved the Templating Tutorial:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/9.5/en-us/MinimalDesign/Index.html

There is described to store the HTML file under

`page.1.file = fileadmin/sitedesign/Resources/Private/Templates/Minimal.html`

So, let's start with the problems I have:

1. The folder structure (beginning at sitedesign) does not exist.
2. Under the link https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/9.5/en-us/ApiOverview/DirectoryStructure/Index.html is told that the fileadmin directory is used for editors and should not be used for HTML templates. This is in contradiction to the official documentation.

> Note this directory is meant for editors! Integrators should not
>   locate frontend website layout related files in here: Storing HTML
>   templates, logos, Css and similar files used to build the website
>   layout in here is considered bad practice. Integrators should locate
>   and ship these files within a project specific extension.

3. So, where should I store HTML template files?

Comment: fileadmin was used for templates until TYPO 6.2. Nowadays you should use a sitepackage extension see https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/. This docu part is outdated.

Comment: There's a newer TYPO3 tutorial which explains how to build a 'Sitepackage' (simple extension which contains templates, resources and configuration): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/9.5/en-us/Index.html

Comment: @sebkln thank you. But there is not described how to install the sitepackage when I have used composer to install TYPO3.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to store your templates in an extension.
You can use https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/ to generate such an extension. This preset already contains HTML files in a location that makes sense (sitepackage/Resources/[Templates/Layouts/Partials]).

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to use a tool. I first want to understand how TYPO3 works in detail. Also there is no documentation how to integrate the sitepackage in my TYPO3 installation.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add a "raw" answer without a preconfigured sitepackage then.

1. You need to create a new extension by creating a directory (choose a name yourself, I will call it `sitepackage`) unter `typo3conf/ext`
2. Every extension needs to have an `ext_emconf.php` file at least (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/DeclarationFile/Index.html#extension-declaration) so create one in `typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/ext_emconf.php` and add needed information (see the link)
3. Choose where to store your Fluid files. It has become the default to use `typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates`, `typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Private/Layouts`, `typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Private/Partials` and create at least a template. Let's call this file `typo3conf/ext/sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Minimal.html`
4. Use your approach from above

```
page.1.file = EXT:sitepackage/Resources/Private/Templates/Minimal.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this please...](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/9.5/en-us/BasicFluidTemplates/Index.html?highlight=templaterootpaths)

```
    templateRootPaths {
        [...]
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        [...]
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        [...]
    }
```